# Running a program installed from cabal

Tags: haskell, anki

I want to run [this program](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/clanki) hosted on [Cabal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabal_(software)), the official repository of Haskell apps.

First I installed Cabal:

```
sudo apt-get install cabal-install
cabal update
```

Second I installed the program itself:

```
$ cabal install clanki
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading safe-0.3.9...
Downloading strict-0.3.2...
Configuring strict-0.3.2...
Configuring safe-0.3.9...
Building safe-0.3.9...
Building strict-0.3.2...
Installed strict-0.3.2
Installed safe-0.3.9
Downloading clanki-1.2.6...
Configuring clanki-1.2.6...
Building clanki-1.2.6...
Installed clanki-1.2.6
```

Third I tried to run the program:

```
$ clanki --list
clanki: command not found
```

Why is the program not found, despite using [the recommended installation procedure](https://github.com/marcusbuffett/Clanki#installation)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cabal` installs to `~/.cabal`, with the binaries going in `~/.cabal/bin`. You have to [add this path to your `PATH`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/haskell#Preparation_and_.24PATH):

```
export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH"
```

[The Haskell website](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal-Install#Unix) says `cabal` can add symlinks to `~/bin` (which gets automatically added to `PATH`):

> If you decided not to put this directory on your `$PATH` then you can
>   get cabal to symlink binaries into another directory, eg `~/bin`. To
>   use this feature edit `~/.cabal/config` and see the `symlink-bindir`
>   field. Note that the `~/.cabal/config` file is not created until you
>   run a `cabal` command for the first time, eg `cabal update`.